# AdaBoost.M1 and DecisionTreeClassifier in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, adaboost

I'm trying to implement the following pseudocode in python with sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier with depth = 1.

[Pseudocode for AdaBoost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTpi9.png)

However, I'm having trouble with the output (3).
I have stored the fitted classifiers in a list along with the corresponding alpha. I am using the decision trees from sklearn, and the classifier is on this format:

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=1,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
```

I'm getting an error in python:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' and 'int'
```

From my code: ( Classifiers is a list with elements from the iterations 0...M on the format ( Gm(x), errorm, alpham )

```
   for c in classifiers:
       res += c[2]*c[0]
   res = np.sign(res)
```

How can I multiply an int with the corresponding classifiers, and then sum them up to get the final classifier G(x)?
Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

With the line

```
new_classifier = lambda x: sum([c[2] * c[0](x) for c in classifiers])
```

suggested by Иван Судос, I get an object on the form:

```
<function adaBoost.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x1233f80d0>
```

How can the signum function be called on this object function(?)?
Thanks!

Comment: You are misunderstanding the step #3; the idea is not of course to multiply an integer with the classifier itself, it is to multiply the integer with the *prediction* of the classifier

Answer (score 0):

You construct the new classifier incorrectly.
What you need as an output is a **function**, not a **scalar** value. And you are trying to multiply function-object by int.

To do that you can either explicitly define function within this iteration score like:

```
def new_classifier(x):
   result = 0
   for c in classifiers:
       result += c[2] * c[0](x)
   return result
```

OR you can define lambda function:

```
new_classifier = lambda x: sum([c[2] * c[0](x) for c in classifiers])
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I got the last line to work, but do you have any idea of how I could do the signum function on the new_classifier? And how does it make sense to do a signum function of the sum of the classifiers for AdaBoost?

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestion. Do you have any idea how I can go about this?